# Inserting data to related models

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

How to add a new data into related table ? I have two tables, the first is Edisi (Edition in English) table and Jurnal (Journal in English) table. The edisi table will contains many jurnal data, or in English the Edition table will contain many Journals data. My question is, how is the method create and save would look like ? I have created the function but it's not working.

Edisi table :

```
class CreateTableEdisi extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('edisi', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('judul')->unique();
            $table->text('cover')->nullable();
            $table->timestamps();
        });

        //Set FK di kolom id_edisi di table Jurnal
        Schema::table('jurnal', function(Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('id_edisi')->references('id')->on('edisi')->onDelete('cascade')->onUpdate('cascade');
        });
    }

    public function down()
    {
        Schema::table('jurnal', function(Blueprint $table) { 
            $table->dropForeign('jurnal_id_edisi_foreign');
        });

        Schema::drop('edisi');
    }
}
```

Jurnal table :

```
class CreateTableJurnal extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('jurnal', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('judul', 200);
            $table->string('penulis');
            $table->text('abstrak');
            $table->text('file');
            $table->integer('id_edisi')->unsigned();
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('jurnal');
    }
}
```

Controller :

```
public function create()
    {
        return view('jurnal/create');
    }

    public function store(JurnalRequest $request)
    {
        $input = $request->all();

        //Input PDF
        if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
            $input['file'] = $this->uploadPDF($request);
        }

        //Insert data jurnal
        $jurnal = Jurnal::create($input);

        return redirect('jurnal');
    }
```

Show View :

```
@extends('template')

@section('main')
<div class="container sitecontainer single-wrapper bgw">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 m22">
            <div class="widget searchwidget joblist">

                <div class="large-widget m30">
                    <div class="post row clearfix">
                        <div class="col-md-4">
                            <div class="post-media">
                                <img alt="" src="{{ asset('fotoupload/' . $edisi->cover) }}" class="img-responsive">
                                <a class="btn btn-primary btn-block">{{ $edisi->judul }}</a>  
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div class="col-md-8">
                            <div id="siswa">
                                <h2>Daftar Jurnal</h2>

                                @if (count($jurnal_list) > 0)
                                <table class="table">
                                    <thead>
                                        <tr>
                                            <th>Judul</th>
                                            <th>Penulis</th>
                                            <th>Action</th>
                                        </tr>
                                    </thead>
                                    <tbody>
                                        <?php foreach ($jurnal_list as $jurnal): ?>
                                            <tr>
                                                <td>{{ $jurnal->judul }}</td>
                                                <td>{{ $jurnal->penulis }}</td>
                                                <td>
                                                    <div class="box-button">
                                                        {{ link_to('jurnal/' . $jurnal->id, 'Detail', ['class' => 'btn btn-success btn-sm']) }}
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="box-button">
                                                        {{ link_to('jurnal/' . $jurnal->id . '/edit', 'Edit', ['class' => 'btn btn-warning btn-sm']) }}
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="box-button">
                                                        {!! Form::open(['method' => 'DELETE', 'action' => ['JurnalController@destroy', $jurnal->id]]) !!}
                                                        {!! Form::submit('Delete', ['class' => 'btn btn-danger btn-sm']) !!}
                                                        {!! Form::close() !!}
                                                    </div>
                                                </td>
                                            </tr>
                                        <?php endforeach ?>
                                    </tbody>
                                </table>
                                @else
                                <p>No Journals yet.</p>
                                @endif

                                <div class="tombol-nav">
                                    <a href="../jurnal/create" class="btn btn-primary">Add new Journal to this edition</a>
                                </div>
                            </div> <!-- / #jurnal -->
                        </div>
                    </div><!-- end post -->
                </div><!-- end large-widget -->
            </div><!-- end widget -->
        </div><!-- end col -->
    </div><!-- end row -->
</div><!-- end container -->
@stop
```

I'm new to Laravel and I'm stuck here. I tried everything I could (look at the controller) and when I try to add the journal data in the selected edition, it shows me error Constrains Fails. Thanks for your help!

Comment: in your controller function is it the model instance you are passing ?

Comment: $jurnal_list = edisi::with('Jurnal')->where('id_edisi', '=', $edisi->id)->get();

Comment: no, its the route model binding to get the id, I guess ?

Comment: it's working now with a little modification to this "$jurnal_list = Jurnal::with('Edisi')->where('id_edisi', '=', $edisi->id)->get();" thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First change `$table->integer('id_edisi')->unsigned();` on your "jurnal" table to `$table->integer('edisi_id')->unsigned();`

Then add following method to "Jurnal" model

```php
public function edisi()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Edisi');
}
```

if you don't like to change jurnal table as I showed earlier, modify above method as follows

```php
public function edisi()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Edisi', 'id_edisi');
}
```

Then in controller

`$jurnal_list = Jurnal::with('edisi')->get();`

If you want to access "jurnal" from "edisi" add following method to the "Edisi" model

```php
public function jurnals()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Jurnal');
}
```

or for unmodified jurnals table.

```php
public function jurnals()
{
    return $this->hasMany('App\Jurnal', 'id_edisi');
}
```

Then in controller

`$jurnal_list = Edisi::with('jurnals')->get();`

Note: make sure to add `$table` variable to "Jurnal" and "Edisi" models, because normally table name needs be like s(ex:- Model: Post Table: posts, Model: Comment Table: comments)

Comment: Thank you, it's solved already. I was just messed up with the controller. Now I have one more question if you don't mind, I have a method create Jurnal in the view, how to add a new Jurnal data in the selected Edisi ? for example, there is a photo album and when you click on it the album is still empty and there you will find a button to upload new photos. My question is, how to add the photos to the album ? assuming that the album has one-to-many relationship with photo, one album has many photos

Comment: you can use save or save many methods `$album->photos()->save( new App\Photo(['foo' => 'bar']));` `$album->photos()->saveMany([ new App\Photo(['foo' => 'bar']), new App\Photo(['foo' => 'bar'])]);` https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/eloquent-relationships#inserting-related-models

Comment: Still I don't really get it, I've updated the question and please take a look if you don't mind, thank you

Comment: You have to pass edisi id from view to controller via hidden input. Then if input name is edisi_id `App\Edisi::find($request->get('edisi_id'))->jurnals()->save(Jurnal::create($request->except(['_token', 'edisi_id']));`

Comment: so I have to create another hidden input in the create form for the edisi_id ?

Comment: If you can use url pattern like "edisis/1/jurnals" you can use $id variable on store method to get edisi id `public function store(JurnalRequest $request, $edisi_id)` then App\Edisi::find($edisi_id)->jurnals()->save(‌​Jurnal::create($requ‌​est->except(['_token‌​', 'edisi_id']));` In this way you don't have to pass edisi id through input field, and url are more understanble.

Comment: Somehow you should be able to get edisi id from the jurnal store method

Comment: <a href="../jurnal/create" class="btn btn-primary">Add new Journal to this edition</a></div> by using url, how to get the session id and add it to url that goes to create jurnal form ? I just started learning Laravel in less than a week ago so I'm sorry if I'm asking too much XD

Comment: In your index method on JurnalController you can get edisi_id to get related jurnals right? so pass it back to index view and then you can add it to <a href="../jurnal/create?edisiid={{$edisi_id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Add new Journal to this edition</a></div>. and on jurnal create method pass it back to create view(you can get url parameters from $request->get('edisiid')). then you can add it as a hidden input. As I mentioned earlier better and recomandded way of doing this through urls. As an example if you want jurnal 1 on edisi 1 url should be like edisis/1/jurnals/1

Comment: goddamn it I forgot, gonna try this now, thank you so much!